# Why [Errno 13] Permission denied?

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

So, I made this .py script that basically downloads excel tables from the USDA. When I run it manually from the prompt command it works, but when I use Task Scheduler to run it, it gives  me the: `Errno 13 Permission denied. click the link below`. My question is, how can it run from the prompt command when I do it manually but not work when I use task scheduler?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, not the link. Just click on 'enter image description here'

Comment: Please don't post links to your code or errors, please just cut and paste it into SO. Which user are you running the task as and do they have permission to create files in the specified folder.

Comment: What do you mean by 'which user'? It's my account and I honestly do not know anyhting about permission. I thought if it worked when ran manually it would also work when scheduled to run with task scheduler

Comment: You're using a relative path. What are you setting the working directory as in the task definition? It may be defaulting to System32 or some other system directory where you don't have access and shouldn't be creating files. Do NOT run the task as administrator (highest privileges). That is not a panacea. Unless you're installing software or administering the system, having to run as admin almost always means you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and this is how I solved it:
-Right click on the task 
-A new window will open up, then at the very bottom of the window check "Run with highest privilege" and this should solve the problem.

Check the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to give read and write permissions to your xls file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Right click
--> Run as administrator

Should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, where should I right click in order to get the 'run as administrator' option? thanks

Comment: where should I right click in order to get the 'run as administrator' option? thanks